# URLRewriteFilter - pointing subdomain to subfolder

Tags: java, subdomain, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Currently all my domain requests are being directed to www using the following URLRewrite Rule:

```
 <rule>
        <name>Canonical Redirect</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^test.com</condition>
        <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^$</condition>
        <from>^/(.*)</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">http://www.test.com/$1</to>
    </rule>
```

I have 2 requirements:

1. I have a domain child.test.com - I do not want this domain to direct to www.test.com
2. I need this child.test.com to point to a subfolder without showing that in the browser URL: 
   i.e Typing child.test.com should actually call test.com/child at the backend without changing the url in the browser.

I believe I can use the following code, but seems like I am missing something. Thanks for all the help!

```
<rule name="RedirectTo" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="http://child.test.com" />
       <action type="Redirect" url="http://test.com/child" />
 </rule>
```

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I am having the same problem with this.